# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to declare a state then make an API call then set the state but I'm encountering `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:` Error. I have checked my react version and react dom and it is fine and I do not have two copies of React. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
function RandomScreen(){
    const [State, setState] = useState([])
    
    let history = useHistory()
    var style = require('./Random.css')
    
    useEffect(async function(){
        // Make API call
        .then(function(response){
            setState(response.data)
        })
    }, [])
    
    async function handleClick(){
        // Make API call
        // Set State again
    }
    return (
        // Some HTML code
    )
}
```

App.js

```
function App(){
    return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/random">
              <RandomScreen />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

After some debugging I found out that `let history = useHistory()` is the cause of this problem but I need `useHistory` hook

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a sandbox like https://codesandbox.io ? If not, this issue will most likely be fixed after reinstalling the dependencies (Remove package-lock.json and node_modules. And reinstall the deps back. PS: be careful when deleting files).

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` callback cannot be async.  First define the async function then call it.
Change this to:

```
useEffect( () => {
    
    async function apiCall() {
        // Make API call
    }
    
    apiCall()
        .then(function(response){
            setState(response.data)
        })
},[])
```

Comment: This doesn't work too but thanks for trying to help me though!

Comment: Nothing about the code you posted is an 'invalid hook call' as far as I can tell, so likely this error is coming from somewhere else.  Perhaps post the entirety of the error. (stack trace)